# Quartz.Net demo application is throwing error

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

i have downloaded a quartz demo application from  [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=61d0a67d27b527d3&id=61D0A67D27B527D3!3363). But when i try to runt this sample application it is throwing the following exception 
I have given the full permissions on the folder and running the VS2012 as an Admin. Any help would be appreciated greatly!

```
System.IO.FileLoadException was caught
  HResult=-2146234304
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz, Version=2.0.1.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=mscorlib
  FileName=Quartz, Version=2.0.1.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4
  FusionLog=WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
       at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
       at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryRequestMessage(String objectUri, Stream inputStream, Boolean bStrictBinding, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Quartz.Simpl.IRemotableQuartzScheduler.CheckExists(JobKey jobKey)
       at Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass6c.<CheckExists>b__6b(IRemotableQuartzScheduler x) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\RemoteScheduler.cs:line 450
       at Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.CallInGuard[T](Func`2 func) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\RemoteScheduler.cs:line 574
       at Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.CheckExists(JobKey jobKey) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\RemoteScheduler.cs:line 450
       at HelloWorldQuartzDotNet.ScheduledJob.Run() in g:\SaiKiran\QuartzExamples\HelloWorldQuartzDotNet\HelloWorldQuartzDotNet\HelloWorldQuartzDotNet\ScheduledJob.cs:line 35
       at HelloWorldQuartzDotNet.Program.Main(String[] args) in g:\SaiKiran\QuartzExamples\HelloWorldQuartzDotNet\HelloWorldQuartzDotNet\HelloWorldQuartzDotNet\Program.cs:line 15
  InnerException: <br/>
```

Comment: Make sure Quartz.dll presents in the bin folder.

Comment: So, did you follow the directions given in plain english in the error message on how to find out whats wrong? If not, why not?

Comment: @abatishchev Quartz.dll is there in bin folder

Comment: Enable assembly bind failure logging and you'll learn what's wrong.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest or the same Quartz.dll version in both places

Comment: I have checked this many times..i have latest...but when i make my assemble as shared then it is working fine...